# Silverlight: ComboBox Behavior

Tags: c#, silverlight, combobox

really simple problem, but I guess I have just the wrong definition of combobox:
I'd like to get a simple thing like: 
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/combobox-in-silverlight/

But whenever I add a combobox (or a listbox) and set the itemssource, it shows directly all items and I dont have a textbox-like selection.

My approach was quite simple:

In XAML I define:

```
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource styleStdWidth}" Text="Spieler 1:" />
                    <ListBox  x:Name="lsbPlayerOne" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource dtName}" Width="300" />
                    <TextBox x:Name="txtPlayerOnePoints" Style="{StaticResource stylePlayerWidth}" />
                </StackPanel>


    <DataTemplate x:Name="dtName">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="35" FontWeight="Bold" x:Name="txbname"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

And in Code behind I just set the ItemsSource with a List, which has data.
Since the ListBox gets bigger every time I add a item, it gets uglier and uglier.

Am I missing a property, which I didnt find? I did not see anything...

Sorry for the confusing question :)

P.S.: I tried the same as in the example shown in the link. Sadly I cant open the sample project.

Matthias Müller

Comment: You question is unclear. What is exactly wrong with it? In your template, you're using a `TextBlock`, not a `TextBox`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear. But you are not implementing a combobox in the code you have shown. Why don't you use a combobox and set your itemsource to the list that contains the fields you want to use?

```
<ComboBox ItemSource={Binding Names}/>
```

Comment: Sorry, I wrote I tried with ComboBox and ListBox, both times with the same result. 
As I wrote, all I basically want is a combobox shown in the link, but I get a thing, which expands with every new item.

I dont know how to describe it, probably I can upload some screenshots to show what I mean?

Since I'm quite new to this stuff, it is possible that I made a fundamental error, but I can't find anything which gives me a hint.